# Cookies on Local Storage?

Tags: javascript, cookies, local-storage

I was creating a small project and was testing local Storage. When I press in the dev tools(Chrome) in the application tab and press local storage it shows besides the data of my project this:

```
google_experiment_mod13: "765
_geo_cc_cache:
```

Anybody knows why and what this is?
From my search, I found something about cookies but didn't find any good explanation.
Anyone can share more info with me?
Much appreciated

Comment: top one is a persistent tracking cookie used by Google AdSense for experimenting with advertisement efficiency across websites (you missed a number at end), second one is most likely the same but does not look like google. These type of cookies is why there is GDRP and cookie laws. Delete them your site will be fine.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thank you. Yeah, I did when I see them, was just wondering because they were in localStorage also. Thanks for the info